# Копирование новых файлов в проект на Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

При копировании новых файлов в проект на Netbeans, старые файлы, имеющие такое же имя, не удаляются, а новые просто переименовываются. Как сделать так, чтобы при копировании файлы с таким же именем заменялись?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, как вы копируете? Какая ОС?

Comment: ОС Windows 7. Копирую обычно, ctrl-c нужный файл, затем открываю нужную папку в Netbeans, ctrl-v. Проект находится на удаленном сервере, синхронизация по sftp.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае это решаемо, если копировать средствами ОС, а не напрямую через Netbeans.

Например, если копировать через командную оболочку, то нам нужен параметр `-f` команды `mv`. С этим параметром все файлы будут перезаписаны автоматически, не требуя подтверждения.

```
mv -f source/path/* target/path
```

Comment: Нужно копировать напрямую в Netbeans, т.к. проект находится на удаленном сервере. ОС Windows 7.